# Retry a Google Cloud Data Fusion Pipeline if it fails

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

We have several cloud data fusion pipelines and some fail, for seemingly random reasons. Albeit rarely.

Is there a way to automatically retry a pipeline if it fails, say 3 times?

Answer (score 1):

You can automatically retry a pipeline if it fails using triggers. When it fails, you need to `STOP` and `START` the pipeline.

To use triggers with Data Fusion, select the event you need to execute, in this case it will be the event `Fails`. You can see this documentation about [creating triggers](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/using-triggers#create_inbound_trigger).

Next you need to `STOP` and `START` the pipeline. This is documentation about [stop and start the pipelines](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/1.0.0/operators/cloud/datafusion.html#start-a-datafusion-pipeline).